# Transform a array php

Tags: php, arrays, string, function, loops

I would like to know if I can transform my array from state 1 to state 2 like the example below.

**state 1 (example)**:

```
array(5) { 
        [0]=> array(10) { 
                ["id"]=> "6" 
                ["name"]=> "peter" 
                ["date"]=> "2020-09-25" 
                ["sleep"]=> "20" 
                ["pain"]=> "30"...
        [1]=> array(10) { 
                ["id"]=> "6" 
                ["name"]=> "peter" 
                ["date"]=> "2020-09-26" 
                ["sleep"]=> "80" 
                ["pain"]=> "90"...
        [2]=> array(10) { 
                ["id"]=> "10" 
                ["name"]=> "john" 
                ["date"]=> "2022-09-25" 
                ["sleep"]=> "25" 
                ["pain"]=> "15"...
        [3]=> array(10) { 
                ["id"]=> "10" 
                ["name"]=> "john" 
                ["date"]=> "2022-09-25" 
                ["sleep"]=> "55" 
                ["pain"]=> "65"...
        [4]=> array(10) { 
                ["id"]=> "6" 
                ["name"]=> "peter" 
                ["date"]=> "2020-09-27" 
                ["sleep"]=> "40" 
                ["pain"]=> "60"...
```

`ID = 6` and `Name = peter` appear 3 times and `ID = 10` and `Name = john` appear 2 times.

**State 2**:

```
array(2){
        [0]=>array() {
                ['id']=> "6" 
                ['name']=>"peter" 
                ["dates" => [2020-09-25, 2020-09-26, 2020-09-27]] 
                ["sleeps" => [20, 80, 40]] 
                ["pains" => [30, 90, 60]]
        [1]=>array() {
                ['id']=> "10" 
                ['name']=>"john" 
                ["dates" => [2022-09-25, 2022-09-25]] 
                ["sleeps" => [25, 55]] 
                ["pains" => [15, 65]]
}
```

The idea is to have an array with only once the same ID and the same name then arrays with the values ​​of the same field such as

```
(id => 1, name => kevin, [dates => [date1, date2, date3]], [sleep => s1, s2, s3]]
```

from this same user.

`ID = 6` and `Name = peter` appear 1 time and `ID = 10` and `Name = john` appear 1 time but each with all their own data.

I hope I was understandable.

Comment: Is this data coming from a database?

Comment: Hi can you please show what code you have used to attempt to convert the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. As your `id` seems to be unique, iterate it and create new array using your `id` index as the main index, you can use [array_key_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to do it. It should look like this after all:

```php
array(2){
        [6]=>array() {
                ['id']=> "6" 
                ['name']=>"peter" 
                ["dates" => [2020-09-25, 2020-09-26, 2020-09-27]] 
                ["sleeps" => [20, 80, 40]] 
                ["pains" => [30, 90, 60]]
        [10]=>array() {
                ['id']=> "10" 
                ['name']=>"john" 
                ["dates" => [2022-09-25, 2022-09-25]] 
                ["sleeps" => [25, 55]] 
                ["pains" => [15, 65]]
}
```

That's 5-minutes craft and I'm pretty sure you'll do it yourself.

```php
<?php
$data = [
    [
        'id'    => '6',
        'name'  => 'peter',
        'date'  => '2020-09-25',
        'sleep' => '20',
        'pain'  => '30'
    ],
    [
        'id'    => '6',
        'name'  => 'peter',
        'date'  => '2020-09-26',
        'sleep' => '80',
        'pain'  => '90',
    ],
    [
        'id'    => '10',
        'name'  => 'john',
        'date'  => '2022-09-25',
        'sleep' => '25',
        'pain'  => '15',
    ],
    [
        'id'    => '10',
        'name'  => 'john',
        'date'  => '2022-09-25',
        'sleep' => '55',
        'pain'  => '65',
    ],
    [
        'id'    => '6',
        'name'  => 'peter',
        'date'  => '2020-09-27',
        'sleep' => '40',
        'pain'  => '60'
    ]
];

$newArr = [];

foreach ($data as $oldItem) {
    $id = $oldItem['id'];
    if (!array_key_exists($id, $newArr)) {
        $newArr[$id] = [
            'id'    => $id,
            'name'  => $oldItem['name'],
            'dates' => [$oldItem['date']],
            'sleeps' => [$oldItem['sleep']],
            'pains'  => [$oldItem['pain']],
        ];
    } else {
        $newArr[$id]['dates'][] = $oldItem['date'];
        $newArr[$id]['sleeps'][] = $oldItem['sleep'];
        $newArr[$id]['pains'][] = $oldItem['pain'];
    };
}

echo "<pre>JSON:\n";
echo json_encode($newArr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo "\n\nprint_r():\n";
print_r($newArr);
```

Comment: Actually I made it in 2 minutes, including data cleaning...